# PHP List all HTML files in Folder with <a> tags

Tags: php, html, glob

I have a html file listing links to artists' pages. What I want to do is to use a php script to list them instead of listing them manually. I also would like to have a thumbnail image above each corresponding link, but I want to get the links first before I add the images. I'm using the following script but it's not working:

```
<?php

$directory = "C:/wamp/myprojects/UMVA/web/includes/artists";
$phpfiles = glob($directory . "*.html");

foreach($phpfiles as $phpfile)
{
    echo '<a href="'.basename($phpfile).'">'.$phpfile.'</a>';
}

?>
```

The folder containing the html files is artists. It doesn't work using the full pathname and it doesn't work using just 'artists' or '/artists' as the pathname. The 'artists' folder is in the same directory 'web' as the php file with the script. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "it's not working"? Do you get a php error? Is the generated link wrong? If so, what is your script generating compared to what it should be generating? Also, please use something like [getcwd()](http://au1.php.net/getcwd), you should never ever specify full paths like that; what if the path changes?

Comment: Try `/` after `artists` or before `*.html`. (so like: `"/*.html"`) Maybe it works. Otherwise - what's your output?

Comment: No errors, just a blank page or sometimes it prints: '.$phpfile.''; } ?>

Comment: And if you `print_r($phpfiles)`, do you get anything? And if they're php files, as the variable name implies, shouldn't you be searching for .php in your glob, not .html?

Comment: print_r prints just '.$htmlfile.''; } ?>  I changed the variables to html even though it shouldn't matter what the variable name is

Comment: I would use _grep_: `<? $files = shell_exec("grep -R -l '<a' $directory"); ?>` (note that [`shell_exec()`](http://ca1.php.net/shell_exec) is disabled when php's safe mode is enabled).

Comment: I get the same output. Is there something basic I'm not getting about php output on a page?

Answer (score 2):

this should actually do the trick:

```
$htmlFiles = glob("$directory/*.{html,htm}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

[source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where is the error, but you can also use SPL Iterators, like GlobIterator, in a more reusable way. GlobIterator returns SplFileInfo objects that provides many useful informations about your file.

Here are the doc pages:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.globiterator.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php

Here is an example:

```
$it = new GlobIterator('C:/wamp/myprojects/UMVA/web/artists/*.jpg');

foreach ($it as $file) {
    // I added htmlspecialchars too, never output unsafe data without escape them
    echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($file->getPathname()) . '">' . htmlspecialchars($file->getFilename()) . '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your directory is always 'C:/wamp/myprojects/UMVA/web/artists', I think you can try scandir( $dirname ) instead of glob().

Comment: directory will change when this page is uploaded but the script page will be in the web folder. scandir not working either.

Comment: I just realised that the <a> tags are working but the link obviously doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: I think its trying to find the files in web/ directory not artists:   Firefox can't find the file at /C:/wamp/www/myprojects/UMVA/web/'.basename($htmlfile).'.

Comment: what is the real output <a> tag? Is it like <a href="C:/wamp/www/myprojects/UMVA/web/artists/foo.html">foo.html</a>? please paste one.

Comment: '.$htmlfile.'    that is the hyperlink

Comment: <a href="'.basename($htmlfile).'">'.$htmlfile.'</a>

Comment: Still not working. I'm sure all of the code everyone's shown me works but there has to be something wrong with the way I'm referencing the directory...

Comment: I think the checkpoint here is make sure you get the file names in $phpfiles correctlly. Then you can check $htmlfile and <a href="'.basename($htmlfile).'">. I'm still confusing what file in your directory?

Comment: Ok I finally at least got it to print out, but the links are messed up. I'm using my original code. I tried using pathname ../includes/artists/  and just artists/ and it's printing out like this:  artists/artistname.html. I just want it to print artistname. Also when you click on the link I get an error saying no page found, but it's looking for includes/artistname.html which doesn't exist because it actually should be includes/artists/artistname.html. At least we're getting somewhere!

Comment: What I'm ultimately trying to do is to print out the links and with each link show the corresponding jpg image. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I undestand a bit more. Now there are two places printed out 'artistname'/'artistname.html' from your data.First place is <a href="{url}">, and the second is <a>{link name}</a>. For the first one, {url}, it must be exactly the same as the file name in your directory.if you just print it as 'artistname' instead of 'artistname.html', The page won't be opened, for the Server cannot find any files named 'artistname'. So {url} must be end like 'artistname.html', unless your Web Server Url Rewrite is turned on. For {link name}, you can use many php functions to cut it to 'artistname'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple script that will look for html files in the current directory create and a hyperlink based on the title tag.

```
<?php
// Get all HTML files in the directory
$html_files = glob("*.{html,htm}", GLOB_BRACE);
$url = "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Print out each file as a link
foreach($html_files as $file) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $start = strpos($contents, '<title>');
    if ($start !== false) {
         $end = strpos($contents, '</title>', $start);
         $line = substr($contents, $start + 7 , $end - $start - 7);
         echo "<center><a href=" . '"' . $url . $file . '"' . ">$line</a></center><br>\n";
    }
}
?>
```

**Save this file as index.php place the html files in the folder and browse to the URL.**